# Is the input number even?

Tags: c++

I just wrote this C++ code in Visual Studio. The code is working fine but I wanted to ask whether my code is written in a safe way or not.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <iostream>





int input()


{


    int x;
    std::cin >> x;


    return x % 2;


}





int main()


{


    using namespace std;


    cout << "Enter a digit" << endl;

    int x = input();

    if (input == 0)




        cout << "Even";


    else



        cout << "Odd";


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  You don't say what your code does.  Your title should be a brief summary and the body should include a statement describing what problem the code is supposed to solve.

Comment: I edited the title this time, next time choose a more sensible name

Comment: I think your code is broken. This makes no sense: `if (input == 0)`. `input` is a function.

Comment: glampert is right.  There could not have been tested originally.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't import stdafx**

It is Windows only and you don't need it.

**Remove all those spaces**

The code is hard to follow when you must scroll continuously:

```
#include <iostream>

int input() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x % 2;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter a digit" << endl;
    int x = input();
    if (input == 0)
        cout << "Even";
    else
        cout << "Odd";
    return 0;
}
```

**Always use braces**

Ugly bugs may hide behind not using parenthesis:

```
if (input == 0) {
    cout << "Even";
} else {
    cout << "Odd";
}
```

**In 2015 avoid `return 0`**

The `main()` function is different; the compiler writes that for you.

**Separate input and computation**

If you care about having separate functions (not really necessary in this trivial case) you should define pure functions with no effect on the outside world:

```
bool is_even(int x) {
    return x % 2 == 0;
}
```

**Avoid verbosity**

A middle level language such as C++ must be pretty verbose, anyway for such trivial cases I propose inlining a ternary:

```
cout << ((is_even(x)) ? "Even\n" : "Odd\n");
```

**Don't underestimate yourself**

The program works for full numbers, ask `"Enter a number:"

**The icing on the cake**

`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice (read about that on StackOverflow)

**The final reviewed code**

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_even(int x) {
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter a number:" << std::endl;
    int x; std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << is_even(x) ? "Even\n" : "Odd\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Four things I would complain about.

1. All the extra vertical space.
2. Having `using namespace std;` is bad practice
   (see every other review about C++)
3. Lack of `{}` around blocks of code in `if/else` statement.
4. You don't check to see if the read worked.
   Note if the read fails then `return x % 2;` introduces undefined behavior
   as `x` will never have been initialized.

Checking read worked:

```
if (std::cin >> x) {
   // Good read
}
```